# Compare month extract from date, same year or next year

Tags: sql, ms-access

This SQL statement working fine for the last year, to selecting data where current month is greater than `Subquery` `Max` month match by `ciient_id`. Now, `Subquery` return `Max` month is 12 for the last year whether comparing current month for this year which is 1. That why the SQL statement return 0 record.

I have to find out `client_id`, those who are not exist in the `Subquery` for the current month. Either I can compare with date. Please Help me to get out of here.

```
SELECT c.id, p.pkg_rate AS amount
FROM tbl_client AS c 
INNER JOIN tbl_package AS p ON c.pkg_id = p.id
WHERE c.status=1 AND 
      Month(Date())>(SELECT Month(Max([due_month])) FROM tbl_payment_due WHERE 
      c.id=client_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to format the date into a string first.

```
Format(Date(),"yyyymm") > (SELECT Format(Max([due_month]),"yyyymm") FROM tbl_payment_due WHERE c.id=client_id)
```

A second option is to add a check for the year in the `WHERE` clause (note: my parenthesis may be off a bit).

```
(Year(Now()) > (SELECT Year(Max([due_month])) FROM tbl_payment_due WHERE c.id=client_id)) OR 
((Year(Now()) = (SELECT Year(Max([due_month])) FROM tbl_payment_due WHERE c.id=client_id)) AND (Month(Date())>(SELECT Month(Max([due_month])) FROM tbl_payment_due WHERE c.id=client_id)))
```

Comment: I tried before like your first approach but undone, Now it works perfectly, Thank you so much.